# Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch disaplying in console

Tags: iphone, ios, uistoryboard

I am getting "Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch" statement in console while application is not opening after displaying splash screen. my application:didFinishLaunchWithOptions method is:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
UIViewController *initViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstInfo"];

[self.window setRootViewController:initViewController];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
[self.window makeKeyWindow];
return YES;
```

main.m is as:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));

    }
}
```

The application was previously working fine. It is just a quick not functioning from Today. I am using ARC and Storyboard in the application. Please Suggest.

Answer (score 15):

add a "MainStoryboard" into your project, and set Main Storyboard option in build settings as "MainStoryboard"

then, update the AppDelegate method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
return YES;
}
```

It works.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the controller being returned from the storyboard is not `nil`.

**Edit** While you are at it...where do you create `self.window` ?

Comment: Also, see the next part of my answer

Answer (score 1):

I would step through that in the debugger and make sure lines like

```
[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstInfo"]
```

are returning what you're expecting.

I would make sure that the storyboard view controller in question actually has the identifier "FirstInfo" and not something "Firstinfo" or "FirstInfo ".

I would also make sure that the storyboard is a member of the application target in the file inspector.

Hopefully one of those is the cause.

Answer (score 0):

I have set Main Storyboard option in build settings as "MainStoryboard[image]"

And its working!!!

Comment: This only works because it disregards your code above and sets up the first view automatically, just for the reference of future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

In storyboard, select the rootViewController and check "is initial view controller" in the left utilities menu.